# Webpack, importing full source code for SVG instead of the path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So, I'm using create-react-app which uses Webpack under the hood.

I've recently run into a situation where I would like to pull the source code for an SVG. However, Webpack's default behaviour is to show the path of the file, not the actual code.

eg:

`import Download from './assets/download.svg';`

translates to: `/static/media/download.b251eb57.svg`

Is it possible to directly import the actual code using Webpack?

Comment: Actually I don't think you can import SVGs by default. Weback would complain you need a loader to handle that file type. Since the import is giving you the path, I think you're using the extract-text-plugin? Could you add your Webpack config to the question?

Comment: As noted, I'm using create-react-app which includes a plethora of loaders out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [svg-inline-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader) with webpack. You can install this loader running this command

```
npm install svg-inline-loader --save-dev
```

Add this line in you webpack config file:

```
{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-inline-loader' }
```

You will then be able to import your SVG like this:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
```

To display your SVG, you will have to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` llike this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: logo}} />
```

Comment: Having it test for 'svgi' allowed me to use my existing SVGs without breaking it, and to be able to get the source for the specific SVGs I needed =)